# Mac OS 10.8: apache exiting with code 1

Tags: macos, apache

I've been reading about this issue and have tried many things, but none seem to work for me.  After being very frustrated with XAMPP, I'm trying to setup a development environment locally using the apache that's already installed (along with php and mySQL).

Whenever I do:

```
sudo apachectl start
```

Nothing happens, and the console displays:

```
8/23/13 3:21:08.262 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (org.apache.httpd[1086]) Exited with code: 1
8/23/13 3:21:08.262 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (org.apache.httpd) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

I've tried doing the suggestion that is most common, which seems to be to make a directory for the error log, and chmod 777 it.

If I do:

```
sudo apachectl -t
```

I get:

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.5.120.124 for ServerName
Syntax OK
```

I see that my IP address is in the 3rd line there, and I'm thinking maybe that's the source of the issue?  If anyone can give me any advice as to what might help, that'd be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Having same problem except my '-t' produces 'Syntax OK'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up on this for anyone else that might be encountering this issue, it ended up being something amiss in my Virtual Hosts file. After combing through that, there were some syntax issues going on that was, in turn, causing this issue to happen.

Comment: Care to elaborate @user2658630 as I am having the problem now